# Ionic don't update variable in view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've a question about **Ionic 4** and why **Angula**r  doesn't  update the view in real time whit the new alert controller.

For example I've this simple code for countdown and when finish the timer starts again after click ok in modal alaert.

I've this code in **controller**:

```
   outputRemainingTime: string;
    secondsRemaining:  number = 60;

    initTimer() {
      this.timerTick();
    }

    timerTick() {
    //this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.timerInterval = setTimeout(() => {
         if (this.isPause) { return; }
           this.secondsRemaining--;
           this.outputRemainingTime = this.getSecondsAsDigitalClock(this.secondsRemaining);
           if (this.secondsRemaining > 0) {
               this.timerTick();
            } else {
               this.onFinishSession();
            }
          }, 1000);
       //})
     }

    getSecondsAsDigitalClock(inputSeconds: any) {
      const secNum = parseInt(inputSeconds.toString(), 10); // don't forget the second param
      const hours = Math.floor(secNum / 3600);
      const minutes = Math.floor((secNum - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
      const seconds = secNum - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
      let minutesString = '';
      let secondsString = '';
      minutesString = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes.toString();
      secondsString = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds.toString();
      return minutesString + ':' + secondsString;
    }

    onFinishSession() {
      showAlert()
    }

  async showAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: "Header Title",
      message: "Messaggio",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {
            this.secondsRemaining = 5;
            this.initTimer();  
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

and this code in the view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>timer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    {{ outputRemainingTime }}
</ion-content>
```

The problem is the new async alertController, if replace my alert function whit this the code and view work

```
showAlert() {
    this.secondsRemaining = 5;
    this.initTimer()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using onDidDismiss or onWillDismiss instead:

```
alert.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
  // make model changes here
});
```

Using your example:

```
async showAlert() {
  let resetTimer = false;

  const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
    header: "Header Title",
    message: "Messaggio",
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel'
      },
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: () => {
          resetTimer = true;
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  alert.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
    if (resetTimer) {
      this.secondsRemaining = 5;
      this.initTimer();
    }
  });

  await alert.present();
}
```

Angular not detecting changes from synchronous calls to AlertInput handler functions is probably a bug on Ionic's end, but arguably the workaround above may be considered better form for asynchronous programming.